# Data binding LiveData from Transformation - Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm learning kotlin and android architecture components.
I have a simple use case of a map toggle button on a google map.

I want to use data binding to bind the map toggle button label to a MutableLiveData field in my ViewModel.

I set the mapType val in the MapViewModel from the onCreate method in the Activity. If I understand correctly, this should trigger the mapLabel val to change due to the use of Transformations.map.

Its not working... Why?

Here's my versions:

- Android studio 3.2 Canary 4
- kotlin_version = '1.2.21'
- support = "27.1.0"
- arch_core = "1.1.0"
- databinding = "3.2.0-alpha04"

MapViewModel.kt

```
class MapViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val mapType: MutableLiveData<MapType> = MutableLiveData()

    val mapLabel: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(mapType, {
        if (it == MapType.MAP) "SAT" else "MAP"
    })
}

enum class MapType {
    SAT, MAP
}
```

activity_maps.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="uk.co.oliverdelange.wcr_android_kt.ui.map.MapViewModel" />
    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MapsActivity">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/map_toggle"
                style="@style/Wcr_MapToggle"
                android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|end" 
                android:text="@{vm.mapLabel}" />
        </fragment>    
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

MapsActivity.kt

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var viewModel: MapViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMapsBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_maps)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MapViewModel::class.java)
        binding.vm = viewModel

        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

        // I can do it this way, but I don't want to. 
        // viewModel.mapLabel.observe(this, Observer { map_toggle.text = it })

        // Here is where i'm setting the MapType on the ViewModel.
        viewModel.mapType.value = MapType.MAP
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap
    }
}
```

I've tested the binding with a MutableLiveData object where i set the string in the activity, and it works fine. The problem seems to be with the Transformations.map - have i just understood it wrong?

Also, whilst debugging, i see that the mapType val in my ViewModel has no observers (not sure if this is right or wrong, just interesting)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The issue here was that despite being bound to the `mapLabel` field, the view binding wasn't being updated when the value of the `mapLabel` field changed.

The reason is that I didn't set the lifecycle owner on the binding.

`binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)`

I realised my mistake after reading [this blog post](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-livedata-with-data-binding-7bf85871bbd8) for the 10th time.

My new MapsActivity.kt

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var viewModel: MapViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMapsBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_maps)
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this) //<- NEW!
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MapViewModel::class.java)
        binding.vm = viewModel

        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

        // Here is where i'm setting the MapType on the ViewModel.
        viewModel.mapType.value = MapType.MAP
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap
    }
}
```

On the plus side I learned a lot about how LiveData works internally!

Comment: You can mark this answer as accepted answer.  You are right, I don't usually use this binding in this way (I usually use ObservableField to observe data change). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Its not working... Why?

When you change the value of `mapType`, the value of `mapLabel` doesn't change immediately. You need to set value of `mapLabel` again. For ex, after you set value for `mapType`, you call method to update value of `mapLabel`

```
// Here is where i'm setting the MapType on the ViewModel.
viewModel.mapType.value = MapType.MAP
viewModel.updateMapLabel()
```

Your viewModel:

```
fun updateMapLabel() {
    mapLabel.value =
        if (it == MapType.MAP) "SAT" else "MAP"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer my question. You're just working around the issue. I could do it a number of other ways, as i described in my question. However I want to understand how Transformations.map works, and why its not working in this scenario.

Comment: Why don't you go to the source code of map to read?. Easy to understand clearer.  I have just read the source of `Transformations.map`, still use method `setValue` to change the value of object.

Comment: I have read the source, and the documentation, which is why I have asked this question on here as I believe what i have done should work.